# How to get the files committed using javagit?

Tags: java, git

I've just started working with javaGit in order to gather information about commits to git on a server. I can get the author, subject, message and date but I can't seem to be able to view how many files were changed, which files were changed or even which files were committed. Is this because Git doesn't store this locally? If so how would I go about getting this data and if not why can't javaGit see it?

Comment: So I am using the get files method but its returning a list of empty size which is the problem, also I'm getting zero lines deleted, zero lines inserted and zero files changed

Answer (score 2):

The [`GitLogResponse.Commit.getFiles()`](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/docs/javagit-0.1.0-javadoc/edu/nyu/cs/javagit/api/commands/GitLogResponse.Commit.html#getFiles%28%29) method returns a list of affected files. The [`CommitFile`](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/docs/javagit-0.1.0-javadoc/edu/nyu/cs/javagit/api/commands/GitLogResponse.CommitFile.html) class provides further infomation about the affected file and the number of changed lines.

> `public java.util.List<GitLogResponse.CommitFile> getFiles()`
>
> This returns the list of files affected by a particular commit.